# Array Intersection with likely function in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 lists
one looks like

```
['sdf_ratio_dffv','ewdef','edef_ratio_dcdc']
```

2nd one looks like

```
['%ratio%','%de%']
```

I want to find all the values that matches with the second one maybe with a likely function.

Is that possible in Pyspark/python? Can someone share their expertise here please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please share how your values look like in your dataframe, share sample of the input dataframe and expected output for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by lists. But if you have a data frame and want to find rows that match a list of regexes, you could use "[rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.rlike.html)".

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([["some-ratio-some", 20], ["dd-ratio-dd", 30], ["dd-something-dd", 30], ["dd-de-dd", 30], ["other-other-dd", 30]], ["name", "age"])
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.filter(F.col("name").rlike(".*ratio.*|.*de.*")).show()
+---------------+---+
|           name|age|
+---------------+---+
|some-ratio-some| 20|
|    dd-ratio-dd| 30|
|       dd-de-dd| 30|
+---------------+---+
```

Comment: I think it should work in general. But my query returns nothing because it has brackets in them ('[',']'). Can you provide a solution for that please?

Comment: None the less this is a good starting point.So thank you!

Comment: If you can you provide your current query and the expected result, it would be easier to solve the issue.

Comment: Sure! I had multiple patterns to check and I could not find a way to combine a way to combine al of them dynamically to query the data once with likely condition. So, I switched to arrays but your suggestion to rlike helped me find the answer. I had to replace the '[' and ']' with '%' and '#' because it doesn't work with those. My query looked like-df.withColumn('name',regexp_replace(col('name'),'\[','\%'))\
        .withColumn('name',regexp_replace(col('name'),'\]','\#'))  . you can consider same dataframe as yours along with the assumption that it has brackets in it. Thank you so much!